# UnicodeEncodeError in json

Tags: python, json

I am teaching myself how to parse google results with json, but when I run this code ( which shoud work ), I am getting this error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>`. Can someone help me?

```
import urllib
import simplejson

query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'site:example.com'})
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s&start=50' \
  % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.loads(search_results.read())
results = json['responseData']['results']
for i in results:
  print i['title'] + ": " + i['url']
```

Comment: Can you include a traceback so we can pinpoint the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This error may be caused by the encoding that your console application uses when sending unicode data to stdout. There's [an article](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) that talks about it.

Check stdout's encoding:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding # On my machine I get this result:
'UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use `unicode` literals.](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

```
print i[u'title'] + u": " + i[u'url']
```

Also:

```
jsondata = simplejson.load(search_results)
```

Comment: Well i changed print line from  print i['title'] + ": " + i['url'] to print i[u'title'] + u": " + i[u'url'] but nothing happend. What you mean with jsondata = simplejson.load(search_results)?

Comment: @user1505497: No need to do `.loads(search_results.read())` because the `.load()` function (no 's') does the reading for you (more efficiently).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is in simplejson.loads(search_results.read()) line, possibly because the default encoding your python is picking up is not utf-8 and google is returning utf-8.

Try: simplejson.loads(unicode(search_results.read(), "utf8").